# get data from socket on port

Tags: socket, netstat, unix-sockets

I have a specific service that sends data on port 5555. I need to open socket on shell unix to listen on this port and print output on shell. Service is deployed as docker container.
So, I run container binding port 5555:5555.

I tried to run  `nc -l localhost 5555` on my host but it not work.
I tried to open container shell and run `netstat`. This is the output:

```
# netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 localhost:epmd          localhost:49664         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 localhost:49664         localhost:epmd          ESTABLISHED 
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED      98194 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED      98193 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED      99655
```

I'm sure that service sends data but I cannot receve. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Do you need to listen on TCP or UDP? Is the container binding done on `localhost` address or on an actual IP on an (bridge)-interface?

Comment: I need to open on UDP. Container is run on remote host using -p ```5555:5555 ``` in docker run comand. I prefer to listen from remote host but to be able to listen from localhost can be a first good result. Can nc -l localhost 5555 used to listen from Unix socket? Thanks

Comment: You need to specify `-u` to listen on *UDP* sockets, `-U` for unix domain sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now its work from my container shell. I used ``` nc -u -l localhost -p 5555```.  I add -u and -p option. Now, It does not work from remote host. Using ``` nc -u -l remoteIP -p 5555``` I dont' receve anything.  Reading documentation is not necessary set particulary option to listen from remote host. I'm able to connect to remoteIP.

Comment: You would specify `nc -l -u IP PORT` to `listen` and use `udp`, then bind (locally) to the `IP` on port `PORT`. When you want to receive data from a remote host, `IP` cannot be `localhost` but must be the address of an actually connected interface.